# How to specify the binding path of parent item context from child tree view item which is bounded to another data context in mvvm

Tags: xaml, mvvm, wpf-4.0, treeviewitem

I have a page and tree view. I am using MVVM.

Say my page is using my data viewmodel data context. My tree view is binded to another public object in my view model. Now inside my tree item, I wanted to bind the command in the page view model. How do I refer in the xaml?

code below.

```
<TreeView  Style="{StaticResource MyNodeStyle}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding {**Object in Page ViewModel**)}"   
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"  
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  
        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="440">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" 
                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TreeViewItemConnectionStyle}" >
    <WrapPanel>
        <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Command="{Binding {**Command in Main Page View Model** }}"    
                IsChecked="{Binding Status,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Focusable="False"  
                Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TreeView_CheckBox_Style}"  >
        </CheckBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=treeTextBoxStyle}" />
    </WrapPanel>
```

Any help greatly appriciated!

Comment: Just use the name of your `ICommand` you want to use...

Comment: I used it. It is not triggering when i click the chek box,when i was seeing wpf inspector, it is showing as BindingExpression path error.

Comment: Show the code for the command. Have you heard of AttachedCommands?

Comment: yes. Thats what i have done.   Command="{Binding UpdateRootConnection} and my view model has 

        /// <summary>
        /// To import > button handler
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand UpdateRootConnection
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(UpdateRootConnectionAPI, CanUpdateConnectionsExecute);
            }
        }

Comment: Actually you still not understood the questions. the question was how to refer the ICommand that is not in the item data context but the page data context .  When i was binding with ICommand  , it expects it to be in the object rather than page view model object

Comment: Your question is still not clear! Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455733/updating-a-reference-to-a-command-of-a-nested-viewmodel).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Josh Smith's `RelayCommand` class, then the command

```
private RelayCommand updateRootConnection;
public RelayCommand UpdateRootConnection
{
    get {
        return updateRootConnection ?? (updateRootConnection =
            new RelayCommand(o => SomeMethod(o));
    }
}
```

Where `SomeMethod` is

```
public void SomeMethod(object o) { ... }
```

and the object `o` will hold the `CheckBox`es state (`IsChecked`). Now the binding you want to use is

```
<TreeView  Style="{StaticResource MyNodeStyle}"  
           ItemsSource="{Binding {**Object in Page ViewModel**)}"  
           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}" 
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
           DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
           Height="440">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" 
                                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TreeViewItemConnectionStyle}" >
            <WrapPanel>
                <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          Command="{Binding UpdateRootConnection}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding Status,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          Focusable="False"  
                          Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TreeView_CheckBox_Style}">

                </CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=treeTextBoxStyle}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

where the `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` is passing the `IsChecked` state into your command via the object `o`.

i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks . But the actual problem is it is not wire up with ICommand when i click the check boxes. I followed the same , but still  hooking up with the command.  Any help ?

Comment: What you are saying does not make sense. I have shown you both how to structure the bound command and how to invoke that command with XAML binding. What is wrong? What is happening now? Using my example, what is not working?